# How can I make a if statement say something from multiple numbers from math.random

Tags: lua

```lua
local x = math.random(1,500)

if x == 1 then 
  print("You Got a g")
end
if x == 2-10 then
  print("You Got a f")
end
if x == "11,100" then
  print("You Got a d")
end
if x == "101,200" then
  print("You Got a c")
end
if x == 201-300 then
  print("You Got a b")
end
if x == 301-500 then
  print("You Got a")
end

print(x)
```

so in this script I don't know what to say when I put `(if x == (what to put here) then)`
I'm still learning to script so not that good

Comment: I requested an edit to format the code and remove your second question you appended. Please do not completely change questions, make a new one (or google first, the question seems to be answered somewhere for sure)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Reinisdm answer; you could also simplify the conditions because the first expression is always true.

```lua
local x = math.random(1,500)

if x == 1 then 
    print("You Got a g") 
elseif x <= 10 then 
    print("You Got a f") 
elseif x <= 100 then 
    print("You Got a d") 
elseif x <= 200 then 
    print("You Got a c") 
elseif x <= 300 then 
    print("You Got a b") 
elseif x <= 500 then 
    print("You Got a") 
end
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

To check multiple numbers use `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` with `and`.

```lua
local x = math.random(1,500)

if x == 1 then 
    print("You Got a g") 
elseif 2 <= x and x <= 10 then 
    print("You Got a f") 
elseif 11 <= x and x <= 100 then 
    print("You Got a d") 
elseif 101 <= x and x <= 200 then 
    print("You Got a c") 
elseif 201 <= x and x <= 300 then 
    print("You Got a b") 
elseif 301 <= x and x <= 500 then 
    print("You Got a") 
end 
print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much